# Remotipart JS Not Executing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, remotipart

I have a form that needs to submit a .csv file to the server and then append the words in it to a textarea in my page. I am using Remotipart to upload the .csv using AJAX but I cannot get the javascript in the server response to execute. Here are the relevant parts of my code:

**The Form:**

```
=form_tag(upload_canvas_words_admin_page_widget_widget_instance_path(widget.page, widget),:method=>'post',:remote=>true,:multipart=>true,:class=>"upload_words_csv") do
        = label_tag "Upload File"
        = file_field_tag "file"
        = submit_tag "Upload"
```

**The Controller:**

```
def upload_canvas_words
    @csv_text = params[:file].read
end
```

**The .js.haml file:**

```
= remotipart_response do
    - if remotipart_submitted?
        alert('#{@csv_text}');
        alert('!');
    - else 
        alert('WHYYYYY?');
```

When I look at the response I see the javascript being wrapped in a bunch of html, which I assume has something to do with the iFrame transport. But the javascript never actually executes.

Comment: Did it worked for you? I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: I never got it working, but the developer did respond to a ticket I made: https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart/issues/66

Comment: I have resolved the issue using this https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart/issues/89 and it works for me

Answer (score 0):

Refer this issue. And try to follow the solution given here.

https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart/issues/89

So what happens is that reponse arrives to the browser with html entity (like `&quot;`) inside the textarea. When the js code for evaluation is extracted the html entities are replaced by theirs respective characters (like " to ').

That's a characteristic of a textarea. So it doesn't get executed

Answer (score 0):

Adding `data: {type: :script}` to the form should be the fix